# Error creating DNS HostedZone in k8 (on aws)

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kops

I was in the process of creating a k8 cluster with kops on aws, and I ran into an interesting exception:

```
error running task "DNSZone/foobar" (1m42s remaining to succeed): error creating DNS HostedZone "": InvalidParameter: 1 validation error(s) found.
- missing required field, CreateHostedZoneInput.Name.
```

I created a hosted zone on Route 53 and set the **zone** type to **private**.

I also modified the following VPC settings to "true":

- **enableDnsHostnames**
- **enableDnsSupport**

used software:

**kops - Version 1.6.1 (git-22b22cc)**

**kubectl - Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"8"...}**

I deleted the cluster and created it again, but the same exception persisted. So there must be something I did wrong.

Any advice would be helpful.

tnx,
Tom

Comment: This looks like an invalid input, check this link:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/issues/1610

Comment: tnx, I got it working!